# How do you get the Hierarchy view in Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, test-explorer

I recently started working on Windows Server 2016 and Visual Studio is missing the "Hierarchy View" that I am used to having.

[image]

[image]

This is Visual Studio 2017 Pro.  Is there a setting I can't find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a new feature in VS2017 Update 6,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.6

So you need to upgrade.